# How to run some javascript code only on small screen/mobile devices

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a vue web app which will be used across all devices. I have some code which I want to get executed only on small devices or mobile. Currently I have that code in a if condition with `$(window).width()`, like following:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
  //My mobile specific code
}
```

Is there some better way or vue way of doing this?

**Edit**

For example in one of the component I have:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      fade: false,
      showFilter: $(window).width() > 768
    }
  },
  components: { PrFilter, Pr },
  created () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
      bus.$on('pr-changed', () => {
        this.showFilter = false
        this.fade = false
      })
    }
  }
}
```

in another component, I have:

```
watch: {
  matchingPr: function (filteredPr) {
    if (filteredPr.length) {
      this.pr = filteredPr[0]
      if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
        bus.$emit('pr-changed')
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: You can refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser

Comment: Well small screen width and small device usually coincide, but not always so you need to decide whether you want the code to execute when a user has a small screen or when the user is using a mobile.

Comment: @apokryfos I will prefer the check to be of small screen.

Comment: @Saurabh as suggested, you should try to clump all small screen specific code together somehow. If not then you'll be stuck squeezing these conditions all over the place. This is why current conventional wisdom is to avoid writing different code per device and writing code that would work similarly on everything.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50342804/6013170

Answer (score 8):

you can use

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

navigator.userAgent Method.

Comment: you don't need an 'else' there, because of the first return

Comment: use test instead of match then you don't need the condition function detectMobile() {
  var ua = navigator.userAgent;
  return /Android/i.test(ua)
    || /webOS/i.test(ua)
    || /iPhone/i.test(ua)
    || /iPad/i.test(ua)
    || /iPod/i.test(ua)
    || /BlackBerry/i.test(ua)
    || /Windows Phone/i.test(ua)
}

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is using the plugin called **vue-mediaquery**.

https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-media-queries/

It worked for me.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You can check for condition and load JS as per necessity.

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Comment: But this is vue component specific code scattered in different vue components, not sure if this can be put in a single JS file, let me add this in the question.